# to update the second autocompletetextview based on the value of the first one

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

In my android app i have an autocompletetextview feild to suggest different State names to the user.
the code is as follows:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> state_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,state);
    actv_state=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.edt_state);
    actv_state.setThreshold(1);
    actv_state.setAdapter(state_adapter);
```

then i take the value of this state in a string by using TextWatcher in this way:

```
 TextWatcher state_text=new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        str_state=actv_state.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
actv_state.addTextChangedListener(state_text);
```

After this i am trying to display the city names in another autocompletetextview based on the state selected..
I cant seem to figure out where do i put this code to show the city names based on the state selected????

```
 if(str_state.equalsIgnoreCase("MADHYA PRADESH"))
         {
          ArrayAdapter<String> mp_city_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mp_city);
          actv_city=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.app_city);
          actv_city.setThreshold(1);
          actv_city.setAdapter(mp_city_adapter);
         }

         if(str_state.equalsIgnoreCase("CHATTISGARH"))
         {
          ArrayAdapter<String> mp_city_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mp_city);
          actv_city=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.app_city);
          actv_city.setThreshold(1);
          actv_city.setAdapter(mp_city_adapter);
         }
```

how do i go about that?? I cant seem to figure out !
Please help if anybody knows any solution to this!!
thanks!

Comment: When do you call the last code block? Make sure to set the city adapter whenever your text (str_state) changed.

Comment: i think you have to put this code in the onItemSelected or onItemClick listener so that you can decide which adapter then to set. Now decided which method will be most appropriate

Comment: use str_state in after text changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be inside autocomplete textview itemclick listener

```
 actv_state.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

         if(actv_state.getText().toString().equals("MADHYA PRADESH"))
     {
      ArrayAdapter<String> mp_city_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mp_city);
      actv_city=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.app_city);
      actv_city.setThreshold(1);
      actv_city.setAdapter(mp_city_adapter);
     }

     if(actv_state.getText().toString().equals("CHATTISGARH"))
     {
      ArrayAdapter<String> mp_city_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,mp_city);
      actv_city=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.app_city);
      actv_city.setThreshold(1);
      actv_city.setAdapter(mp_city_adapter);
     }

        }
    });
```

Comment: this does not work...setOnItemclickListner does not work on autocompletetextview

Comment: Have you tried this? Iam using it on my app without having any problems.

Comment: I tried putting this exact same code an i am getting an error `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined`

Comment: have you added any onclick listener to any array adapter?

Comment: In which line your are getting error? Can you post your complete code?

Comment: I figured it out! Problem solved ! your answer was of lot of help for me!thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 TextWatcher state_text=new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             str_state=s.toString();
}
};
```