# How to populate second AutoCompleteTextView based on the first AutoCompleteTextView Selection

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have 2 `AutoCompleteTextViews` in my android app which are loading data from the server. The first one loads Manufacturer name and the second one has to load the models from the chosen Manufacturer Name.

I had a look at [to update the second autocompletetextview based on the value of the first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645536/to-update-the-second-autocompletetextview-based-on-the-value-of-the-first-one) but its of no use to me as I have more than 100 manufacturers nsame. Therefore, I don't want to use 100s of IF statments as it's bad programming practice and code will be messy. My supervisor suggested me to use AJAX (not sure if its supported by android and if it is not don't know how to implement it).

Any suggestion how to implement that concept or if it can be done by AJAX, please tell me a tutorial or and example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SQLite is a key to solve your problem.

There are several options:

1. Store your manufacturer and model list in SQLite.
2. Store your manufacturer and model list in SQLite. Update using HTTP
   request on app launch alongside with other data.
3. Store your manufacturer and model list in SQLite. Update using HTTP
   request on manufacturer select using timestamps to determine whether
   it really needs update.
4. Update model list on manufacturer select using HTTP request.

Decision

- First option if your list of manufacturer and model is not regularly updated on the website and could be updated with the app itself.
- Second and third are viable if the list is updated regularly and you have huge amounts of data to be updated on each request.
- Fourth one is ok, but it highly relies on server availability and connection speed, which could cause usability issues.

Comment: I have all the manufacturers name and in my external database. The first option sounds good to my needs however, can you suggest me a tutorial that does that kind of implementation please.

Comment: Try this one: [Android: AutoCompleteTextView, SQLite, and Dependent Fields](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/11/android-autocompletetextview-sqlite-and-dependent-fields/). It is pretty old, but if you look at the code, you'll get how to deal with dependent AutoCompleteTextViews.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that I have populated the first one by `ArrayAdapter` and getting all the data using `JSON` from the server. Would the concept still be the same?

Comment: If you are getting all the data using JSON from server and not caching it in SQLite, than you are using fourth option written above. The concept is different. There is no point of getting manufacturer list from server, but model list to be stored in SQLite.

Comment: No, both are stored in the server, all I need to do is display model name from the server based on what manufacturer name the user selects.

Comment: [Dependant Spinners from MySql Database](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.com/2012/07/dependant-spinners-from-mysql-database.html)

Comment: Brilliant ! i'll give that a try and let you know :)

Comment: I have just realised that my manufacturers and models are in two different table not one as mention in [Dependant Spinners from MySql Database](http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/dependant-spinners-from-mysql-database.html).Therefore I'm opening a new question. Thanks for your help anyways.